# Propiedad computada en Vue con texto y funciones

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Tengo el siguiente alert:

```
<b-inline-alert
              v-else
              alert-type="warning"
              :alertTitle="i18nTexts.programmedEmailTitle1 + $_parseData_date(cartDetail.will_send_at.date) + i18nTexts.programmedEmailTitle2 + $_parseData_time(this.cartDetail.will_send_at.date)"
              :alertText="i18nTexts.sendLink + this.cartDetail.recovery_url"
              icon-class="w-alert-uploading"
              show
            />
```

y en mis computed lo siguiente:

```
    computed: {
        i18nTexts () {
          return {
         programmedEmailTitle1: this.translateText('Enviaremos un 
         email recordatorio al cliente para que retome la compra el '),
            programmedEmailTitle2: this.translateText(' a las '),
}
```

Se que podria directamente realizar lo que esta pasando en mi alert de forma mas limpia y cargar la funcion aqui mismo desde computed, pero como seria correctamente?

Actualmente funciona correctamente pero deberia corregir que en el

> :alertTitle y :alertText

no debo tener las funciones de

> $_parseData_date y $_parseData_time

. Por lo cual las debo trasladar dentro de computed

Comment: Hola Nicolás, cuéntanos, tienes algún error en tu código? La consola arroja algo? Hay algo que no funcione como deseas? Cuál es el funcionamiento que debería tener? Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta para añadir mucha más información que puede ser de ayuda a las personas que queramos brindarte una mano

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @GermanAlzate actualizo agregando detalles

Comment: Pero puedes tener una `computed property` que encapsule lo que tiene en el `alertTitle`